# Compiling java Code Available In A String within another java code

Tags: java, compiler-construction, compilation, java-compiler-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [On-the-fly, in-memory java code compilation for Java 5 and Java 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616532/on-the-fly-in-memory-java-code-compilation-for-java-5-and-java-6)
>   [Compiling Java file with code from within a Java file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452285/compiling-java-file-with-code-from-within-a-java-file)

i have a hello world class available in the string of a program as given in the example below,

```
public class CompileJavaString {   
  public static void main(String arg[]) {
     String s="public class HelloWorld{ public static void main(String arg[]) ";
     s=s+" { System.out.println(\"Hello World\"); }  } ";
     // this is the complete code of Hello World class taken as an example   

     // code to compile the class Hello World available in string and 
     // generate the HelloWorld.class file required here
  }
```

}

can someone help to compile the code in a memory string available in example given above

Comment: Write the the string to `HelloWorld.java` and call `javac`?

Comment: Here is [the code](http://www.accordess.com/wpblog/an-overview-of-java-compilation-api-jsr-199/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have a look at `javax.tools.JavaCompiler` and related classes.
The documentation contains examples of how to use them.

Note that the java compiler will only work if you have a JDK installed. A JRE is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Save as HelloWorld.java and do following:

```
  String fileToCompile = "HelloWorld.java";
  JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
  int compilationResult = compiler.run(null, null, null, fileToCompile);
    if(compilationResult == 0){
        System.out.println("Compilation is successful");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Compilation Failed");
    }
```

**Edit**

Can have a look at detailed example :

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/CompilingfromMemory.htm

Comment: i don't want to save it to .java file, this is the real task i have to do because i have to save the time consumed while writing to .java file and reading again.

Comment: This might help : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/CompilingfromMemory.htm

Comment: it is giving an exception. NullPointerException